# Problem upgrading Ubuntu from 18.10 to 19.04

Tags: kubuntu, python3, do-release-upgrade

I am trying to upgrade Ubuntu 18.10 to 19.04 using commands:

`pkexec do-release-upgrade -m desktop -f DistUpgradeViewKDE &`

or

`sudo do-release-upgrade -m desktop`

both with the same failure: `Your python3 install is corrupted, please fix the '/usr/bin/python3' symlink.`
Python3(.6) installation seems to be fine. I have also installed Python 3.7. Manually removed and re-created symlinks with no effect.
Also
`apt-get install --reinstall python`
or
`update-alternatives --remove-all python`
didn't help.

python3 points to:
`/usr/bin/python3 -> /usr/bin/python3.6`

I've tried to remove it at all, to link it to python3.7. I also found that the do-release-upgrade needs python 3.5, but in all cases I have the same error. Except that the do-release-upgrade doesn't work at all without python 3.
Any ideas how to perform upgrade to 19.04?

Comment: What's the output of `file /usr/bin/python` (yes, without the 3)?

Comment: Are you following the steps in https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiscoUpgrades/Kubuntu? Did `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` complete without issues? If it didn't, you need to fix that first.

Comment: @DKBose: No, that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

For a long shot.

```
sudo apt install --reinstall python-minimal  python2.7-minimal
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, problem solved: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader/+bug/1825655

I had to run:
`update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python2.7 1
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.6 2
rm /usr/bin/python
ln -s /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python
do-release-upgrade`